# Swift framework wouldn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have created an Cocoa Touch framework with Swift and and created a CocoaPod from it. I imported that framework with CocoaPod into my app project in Swift. In the view-controller where I want to use the framework I add the following:

```
import UIKit
import swiftBAOS
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        BAOS.login()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

There is no error, but when I want to use a class from the framework Xcode gives the following error: "Use of unresolved identifier BAOS"

I hope somebody can help. Thanks.

Comment: Show us where you're using the class from the framework, not just the import.

Comment: I've edited the code above. The BAOS.login() gives the error.

Comment: Show where in `swiftBAOS` you declare the `BAOS` class and the `login()` function.

Comment: The whole repo of the framework is public on github: https://github.com/hengel2810/swiftBAOS